# what is the reason of Export job failed! in sqoop?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I want to export a table from hive to SQL server and I used this statement:

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://10.13.212.40\MSSQLSERVER166;DatabaseName=Workspace" --username sa --password f1s0ft@123 --table "delay3"  --export-dir "/apps/hive/warehouse/delay/part-m-00000" -m 1
```

but I got this error of export job failed

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: And what is the error

Comment: Is `part-m-00000` a directory or a file? Export dir should be a directory.